# As I connect APP OpenShift php with MSSQL remote?

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, openshift, openshift-php-cartidges

I would like to know how to compile mssql in php5.4 of Openshift? I've heard of freetds, but really I'm a bit of a novice with this and have not managed to make it work.

I want to connect to a remote server from my application MSSQL OpenShift php.

you can with a rhc code or install a DIY cartridge?
please help

Answer (score 0):

OpenShift Online does not currently have any of the modules that you would need to connect to MSSQL installed.  You have a couple of options:

1. Visit https://openshift.uservoice.com and add a suggestion for installing modules that would enable you to connect to a remote MSSQL server from the PHP cartridges.
2. Write an API in front of the MSSQL database that enables you to interact with it in the way that you need to.  Maybe using another hosting provider that has the MSSQL extensions installed or a windows hosting provider,etc